# Extract a single value from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python I'm trying to extract a single value from a Pandas dataframe. I know exactly what the value contains, I just need to find it anywhere in the dataframe and extract it.

For example, in the dataframe below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {0: ['BA1234', 'CA:1234', 'DA','DA1234', 'EX DA', 'CA1234'],
         1: ['BA1234', 'CA:1234', 'DA','CA1234', 'EX DA', 'CA1234'],
         2: ['BA1234', 'CA:1234', 'DA','CA1234', 'EX DA', 'CA1234']})
```

I want to extract the string containing the two letters 'DA' and exactly 4 digits after it.

I've been trying this using a mask:

```py
mask = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains('^DA\d{4}', na = False) for col in df]))
```

Which seems to work:

```py
da_value = df[mask]

da_value
        0    1    2
0     NaN  NaN  NaN
1     NaN  NaN  NaN
2     NaN  NaN  NaN
3  DA1234  NaN  NaN
4     NaN  NaN  NaN
5     NaN  NaN  NaN
```

However, how do I extract the value from the dataframe? Is there a better/easier way of doing this?

**Edit:** The output I actually want is

```
da_value = 'DA1234'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) first for `Series`, then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
s = df.stack()
a = s[s.str.contains(r'^DA\d{4}', na=False)].tolist()
```

If need first value from list you can select:

```
print (a[0])
DA1234
```

Or general solution if possible no value exist, then default value is added:

```
print (next(iter(a), 'no match'))
DA1234
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized my question wasn't clear. The result I'm actually looking for is the string itself 'DA1234'

Comment: Awesome, this is what i'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.apply()` to apply `series.str.contains()` along with [`df.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) over `axis=1` to fetch the rows where any column matches the pattern:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'^DA\d{4}', na=False)).any(axis=1)]
```

---

```
        0       1       2
3  DA1234  CA1234  CA1234
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized my question wasn't clear. The result I'm actually looking for is the string itself 'DA1234'

Answer (score 1):

if you only want that row in which a string follows the condition, below works

using [re.findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020213/python-re-findall)

```
df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: True if re.findall('^DA\d{4}',x[0]) or re.findall('^DA\d{4}',x[1]) or re.findall('^DA\d{4}',x[2]) else False, axis=1)]
```

**Output**

```
        0       1       2
3  DA1234  CA1234  CA1234
```

**Updated**

```
df.apply(lambda x: re.findall('^DA\d{4}',' '.join(list(x))), axis=1).any()[0]
```

**Output**

```
'DA1234'
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized my question wasn't clear. The result I'm actually looking for is the string itself 'DA1234'

Answer (score 0):

As you want to search the value anywhere in the dataframe, you could reshape the values to make it a single dimension Series:

```
s = pd.Series(df.values.reshape(len(df) * len(df.columns)))
s = s.loc[s.str.match(r'DA[0-9]{4}')]
if len(s) == 0:
    print('Not found')
else:
    print(s.iloc[0])
```

With your example data it just prints

```
DA1234
```