# Extract r value from pearson correlation data

Tags: python, pingouin

I am using pingouin stat package to find the correlation between two sets of data, and I then want to check if this correlation is strong. However, I get 5-6 output values, of which only one is `r`. How do I obtain the `r` out of the output data?

Code:

```
b = pg.corr(x=df['Bitcoin Start Value'], y=df['Gold Start Value'])
```

Output:

```
          n      r         CI95%     r2  adj_r2     p-val    BF10  power
pearson  35  0.558  [0.28, 0.75]  0.311   0.268  0.000501  70.273   0.95
```

Comment: According to https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.corr.html the `pingouin.corr` function returns a `pandas DataFrame`. According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html you can access elements of such a data frame with the `.at` function, so you should try something like `b.at("pearson", "r")`.Make sure to just check the documentations recursively in such cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract a single value from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187039/extract-a-single-value-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score -1):

Writing `b['r'][0]` will give you the `r` number. The same with the other output variables.

Comment: Sorry my typo (removing `b`) was not intentional. I don't know who voted this down, but the reason might be that there is no indication *why* your solution works, which it of course does. So maybe adding a reference could help that explains the data structure. See above comment by Miiller.